# Visual Studio needs credentials to access pkgs.dev.azure.com on mac

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-devops

I am working on existing Xamarin project on mac which is on AzureDevOps. When I open that project in Visual studio for mac it prompting popup this

[image]

However I logged in Visual Studio by credentials but when try with same credentials here its continuously pops out after hit OK button . and last it say restore package failed.
Also I tried with Windows but its allow to restore all the packages without any hurdles after logged-in in VS2019.
Any Suggestions....

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Please check if The Chris's answer helps you.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it only worked, with the following credentials:

**Username: username@domain**

(e.g. if your email is: "peter.parker@spiderman.com" -> use "peter.parker@spiderman")

**Password: PAT-Key**

The Personal Access Token (PAT) itself only needed Read-Rights for Packaging.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue while using Visual Studio for Mac, i.e., *"Visual Studio need credentials to access pkgs.de.azure.com"* and it keep asking for **username** and **password**. Although I used the same credentials when I cloned the repository from **Azure DevOps**.

What I understand that my Personal Access Token (PAT) has **Code (Read & Write)** scope of access but not the **Packaging (Read)** access that is why, it was unable to restore packages.

I went to **Personal Access Token** settings, and added **Packaging (Read)** access to scope of access and then it worked perfectly. I hope it might be helpful for you :)

[image: setting Packaging (Read) access for PAT in Azure DevOps]

Answer (score 0):

Your Xamarin project probably has some Nuget Packages configured that com from an DevOps Artifact Pipeline. Visual Studio 4Mac is not able to connect to this feed by default.
(Note: Rider and Visual Studio for Windows would show a different Login prompt, that would work!)

The solution is to change the nuget source configuration.
This may help you configuring your nuget feed to connect via Personal Access Token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azure-devops

cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you have your **PAT**(Personal Access Token), enter it in the **Username** field and leave the **Password** field empty.
If you don't I suggest you create a new one and set it to "**Full Access**" and repeat the step above.

Below are the steps to create a **PAT**

1. From your home page, open your user settings, and then select Profile.
   [image]
2. Under Security, select Personal access tokens. Select the token for which you want to modify, and then select Edit.[image: Select Edit to modify PAT]
3. Edit the token name, organization it applies to, token expiration, or the scope of access that's associated with the token, and then select Save.[image: Modify and Save PAT]

Make sure you copy the PAT once you see it, because you won't see it again.